# Cannot boot ISO on only one machine

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, iso-image

I have a version of Ubuntu 14 on DVD and USB to boot from. This ISO boots from other machines via both DVD and USB, but it will not boot on the particular Dell I need it to.

Initialization crashes with:

```
[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(2,0)
```

I have installed Ubuntu partitions on this machine before. The previous installation starting having kernel panics, and I had to select a previous kernel from the GRUB menu.

Since then I have zeroed out that primary drive (via a **Knoppix 7.4** ISO that *does* boot) for this machine multiple times, so I'm not understanding why I cannot boot this installation ISO on this machine, whereas I can with any other.

Machine specs: `Dell OptiPlex 9020/0PC5F7`, `BIOS A05`, 12/05/2013

Comment: As a test, unplug your HDD.  Does the Ubuntu ISO now boot?

Comment: Interestingly, after resetting BIOS and installing the ISO, attaching either of two drives (one internal, one external) with **ext4** filesystems crashed the system. I had to zero these drives out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the specifics of why this worked, but I reset BIOS from the boot-up options there, and could then install this ISO. I really don't recall ever modifying BIOS, but perhaps this did occur somewhere down the line.